# Watchpoints w/xDebug in Eclipse PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

Has anyone gotten watchpoints to work when debugging PHP with xDebug and Eclipse? The way I understand it, I'm supposed to be able to select a watched variable in the expressions view or select a variable in the Variables view during debugging, and then select Run->Toggle Watchpoint. But Toggle Watchpoint is constantly greyed out. All my other debugging functions work fine: breakpoints, step in, out, over, etc. Just can't get a watchpoint working.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out watchpoints aren't supported in Eclipse PDT. Too bad. Maybe in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Window/Show View/Expressions